# Multiple Scoreboard Objectives

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On some servers, the sidebar in the hub has a scoreboard displaying multiple things. For example, on Mineplex it displays the server there on, how many gems they have, how many coins they have, what their rank is and the website. How do they do this? All I can get it to do is display one objective.

I'm playing version 1.7.10.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of servers like Mineplex, they use plugins to create the scoreboards rather than command blocks, but the same approach is taken.

At the current moment it is not possible to display two 'objectives' as such. Instead, you must use fake players as objectives instead.

For example, if you wanted to have two objectives, distance walked (cm) and distance flown (cm) you would have command blocks on a loop (clock) with these commands:

/scoreboard players operation WalkDistance Scores = Sulphate Walked

/scoreboard players operation FlyDistance Scores = Sulphate Flown

In these commands, 'FlyDistance' and 'WalkDistance' are the fake players, 'Scores' is the scoreboard title, and 'Sulphate' is the player name. 'Walked' and 'Flown' are the scores being tracked.

Hope this helped!